# Как сделать такую карту?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, map

Нужна интерактивная карта с флажками на городах и по клику на флажок появляется название города и форма заявки.

Answer (score 1):

Пример интерактивной карты с метками (иконки флажков надо подставить) https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1

Пример макета балуна метки https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout в который вы можете добавить любой необходимый вам контент.